Scrapy force close at timeout limit when TCP connection freezes
In my scpraper I have a specific url which goes down periodically. The finish stats show
 'downloader/exception_count': 2,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 150.027039,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_timeout',

I added CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT=30 in my settings, however the above crawl is taking 150s before terminating with the above stats. why is that?
I also have a custom download timeout set within the scraper:
custom_args = {
    'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 12
}

But this is also not being respected. According to this SO question It seems like an OS connection limit configuration is taking precedence over scrapy related connection limits. Is there no way of adding a hard kill limit for scrapy? Like a middleware or a signal that forces the exit of the scraper?

from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
import time

class TimeoutMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.start_time = time.time()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        timeout = crawler.settings.getint('HARD_TIMEOUT', 180)  # Default to 180 seconds
        return cls(timeout)

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        if time.time() - self.start_time >= self.timeout:
            raise CloseSpider('Reached hard timeout limit')
        return result

You can then activate this middleware in your settings by adding it to the DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES setting.
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.TimeoutMiddleware': 950,
}

Adjust the HARD_TIMEOUT value in your settings to specify the desired maximum runtime for your scraper.

This is not working. I confirm i have added the exact middleware 'myproject.middlewares.TimeoutMiddleware', but timeout is still 150s

The problem with your answer is  process_spider_output: "This method is called with the results returned from the Spider, after it has processed the response."  In my case, the response is not yet completed. my issue is that the url's server is timing out and causing TCPTimedOutError. The solution must be running asynchronously to trigger a force kill anytime.

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
timeout = crawler.settings.getint('HARD_TIMEOUT', 180)  # Default to 180 seconds
return cls(timeout)
you can try using this by adjusting the timeout

Scrapy never terminates instantly in whatever workaround I try. Only one solution solved it. Creating a decorator to directly kill the process after N seconds. This is the decorator
def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Kill the process
            def handler(signum, frame):
                # gracefull shutdown
                os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
                # Forced Shutdown
                os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

            # Set the alarm signal to call the handler after N seconds
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
            signal.alarm(seconds)

            # Call the original function
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # Cancel the alarm signal if function completes before N seconds
            signal.alarm(0)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

Then add this as the decorator to the function that triggers the scrapy crawl
@timeout(10)
def task(**kwargs):
  # ...
  process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  stats = process.crawl(**kwargs)
  process.start()
  # ...

This forced termination with finish_reason shutdown
